# Are geronimo-web.xml files required to deploy to Geronimo?

Tags: java, servlets, geronimo

I have a servlet that I built and ran on Tomcat.  I now need to deploy this servlet to Geronimo.  Do I need to have a geronimo-web.xml file before I cam deploy to Geronimo?  If so, does anyone know of good example online to build one?

Comment: Unless you need some specific settings your war shall be portable. Have you tried?

Comment: I've treid a lot both with and without.  Looks like I have to use them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was only ever able to deploy with them, so I believe the answer is yes.